# "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT:Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" while http-proxy-middleware combined with https-proxy-agent

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware, https-proxy-agent

The Node (Express JS) middle-ware uses *http-proxy-middleware* to proxy requests and responses between client (probably Chrome browser) and jira server. It also uses *https-proxy-agent* to add proxy agent as the host server requires proxy to access Jira APIs.

The request headers have been updated using *onProxyReq*. It completely works fine in localhost as it doesn't require proxy agent but it throws an error *"ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT:Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"* in server.

The code implementation is below

```
var express = require("express");
var proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
var HttpsProxyAgent = require("https-proxy-agent");

var router = express.Router();
// proxy to connect open network
var proxyServer = "http://myproxy.url:8080";

router.use(
  "/jira",
  proxy({
    target: "https://myJira.url",
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer),
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq: function(proxyReq, req, res) {
      proxyReq.setHeader("user-agent", "XXX");
      proxyReq.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
      console.log(
        "Printing Req HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(proxyReq.getHeaders())
      );
    },
    onProxyRes: function(proxyRes, req, res) {
      proxyRes.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
    },
    pathRewrite: {
      "^/api/jira/": "/" 
    }
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

Appreciate any help to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

`http-proxy-middleware` use internally `http-proxy` module.

In `http-proxy` module, there is an open issue about using `proxyReq` (or `onProxyReq` for `http-proxy-middleware`) when behing a corporate proxy : https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy/issues/1287

The workaround found by b44x is to use `proxy.web` low-level method from `http-proxy` module.

I encountered the same problem, and I solved it this way:

```
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');


// define an agent to proxy request to corporate proxy
const proxyAgent = require('proxy-agent');
// get values from environnement variables and avoid hard-coded values
const corporateProxyUrl = process.env.https_proxy || process.env.HTTPS_PROXY || process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY || '';
const agent = corporateProxyUrl ? new proxyAgent(corporateProxyUrl) : false;


const myLocalProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

const myServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  // change request before it's being sent to target
  delete req.headers.origin;

  myLocalProxy.web(req, res, {
    // instruct 'http-proxy' to forward this request to 'target'
    // using 'agent' to pass through corporate proxy
    target: 'https://www.example.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: agent,
    toProxy: true,
  });

});

myServer.listen(8003);
console.log('[DEMO] Server: listening on port 8003');
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the open bug, so, can't I use this proxy-agent inside express' router.use()?